# Collision detection using point clouds

Tags: ros, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm presently using dynamic edt3d library to compute the closest obstacle to a point. If this distance is greater than a certain clearance, I say that the point is collision free for the robot. However, let's say I'm planning to use a robot of dimensions 4 * 2 * 0.5, then my clearance will have to be 4m which is too much. How can I effectively collision check keeping robot dimensions in mind? Finding the intersection of point cloud with robot shape point cloud might not be the most effective way I'm guessing.

Any and all suggestions are welcome. Thank you for your time!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266840/collision-detection-using-point-clouds/) by [swethmandava](https://answers.ros.org/users/26039/swethmandava/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2017-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Distance transforms with multiple resolutions in each axis might be the fastest and simplest solution to this problem. However, if the robot structure is complicated, you can use FCL for point cloud collision.

---

Originally posted by [swethmandava](https://answers.ros.org/users/26039/swethmandava/) with karma: 102 on 2017-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just came across the Flexible Collision Library ([FCL](http://wiki.ros.org/fcl)). The wiki page links to a paper, which claims, that FCL can do collision checks on point clouds. I haven't tried the library myself, so I cannot recommend the library from my own experience. But the paper and the video are quite impressive.
Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-07-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [swethmandava](https://answers.ros.org/users/26039/swethmandava/) on 2017-07-25**:
Thank you, I checked it out and it seems like a perfect solution for a complicated robot structure. Since I'm only using a cuboidal uav, I found that using distance transforms with multiple resolutions (in x, y and z) might be a faster and simpler solution.